# How do I keep flexbox containers 50/50 with a large image involved?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a Flexbox setup comprised of two div elements which are both taking up 50% of the width of the screen equally.

The left side will have some text and the right side will have an image which will **only** fill the whole of it's 50% of the width, shrinking larger images down if necessary.

What's the best way to achieve this? I'm fairly new to Flexbox.

```css
.content{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
.content div{
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
}
.text{
    background-color: pink;
}
.image{
    background-color: paleturquoise;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
    <div class="text">
        <p>text goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rcZLIwH.jpg" alt="image">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: max-width:100% to image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `.image` `position: relative` and set the `width` of the image to `100%`:

```css
.content{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
.content div{
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
}
.text{
    background-color: pink;
}

.image{
    background-color: paleturquoise;
    /* make the parent position relative */
    position: relative;
}

.image img {
  /* make the width of the image equal to the parent width */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
    <div class="text">
        <p>text goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rcZLIwH.jpg" alt="image">
    </div>
</section>
```